# Android Studio Freezes randomly while device is connected

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a new installation of Android Studio, 1.3.2.  I'm new to android programming so I haven't had this installed here before, but I did have the android SDK installed a long time ago so I could root my phone via adb.  Still, presumably when I installed studio and downloaded the new sdk it should've overwritten any older files I had.

My problem is that about 30 to 40 percent of the time when I'm testing my app, the entire IDE just freezes.  I hit the little Play icon on the header, it loads to my phone, the phone gets the app, I can test it.  Most of the time it works, sometimes I lose all ability to interact with studio.  The app on the phone works fine, but nothing brings studio back.  Importantly, this is NOT a Windows style "not responding" bug.  I can maximize and minimize the window and drag it around without it going grey, and task manager doesn't give me the "not responding error".

It stays like this until I unplug my phone, at which point it immediately executes all of the button presses that were queued up while I was trying to click places.  This makes debugging rather difficult, as I can't actually see logcat and follow along.

I do get the following errors in the ADB Logs tab whenever I plug in either of my two phones

> PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 44f76320: device offline
>
> PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 44f76320: device unauthorized.
>
> This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
>
> Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
> PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 44f76320: device unauthorized.
>
> This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
>
> Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
>
> DeviceMonitor: ExecutionException getting info for device 44f76320

I've revoked the USB Debugging Authorizations on both phones and confirmed via the popup dialog that I want to trust this computer, but I don't know if these errors are involved in this problem or not.

One last thing that may or may not be related: sometimes even when it doesn't entirely freeze, logcat is ridiculously unresponsive.  I'll crash my program on a null pointer, and it'll take upwards of 30 seconds for the stack trace to show up (this is not, by the way, a very large program if that matters).  Sometimes it never shows up at all, even though things are connected and seem to be working, I just get nothing at all in logcat.

Thoughts?  Even just ideas on what to try next would be most appreciated, I'm stuck and most of my googling seems to be bringing up very different issues than the ones I'm having.

Comment: Update as I keep working on this issue: I did have two complete sdk folders on my computer, one called sdk and one called sdk1.  I believe one was leftover from my earlier install.  I uninstalled Android Studio and it took sdk1 with it.  I deleted sdk, and looked around and didn't see any other android stuff installed anywhere.  Rebooted the computer, did a fresh install of studio.

Second time I loaded something to the phone, it locked up just like normal.  No difference on a completely fresh install.

Comment: I am experiencing this on OSX Mavericks, so not exactly the same issue, but maybe upgrading OSX will help the way upgrading Windows helped for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this, I eventually solved it after upgrading from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.  I didn't do a fresh install, I just ran the upgrade process.  When I first launched Android Studio, it had to update a few things, and one of the things it updated was the Google USB Driver.  I'm willing to wager that was my problem all along, and the OS upgrade wasn't at all necessary.

So if you have this problem, try updating your USB Driver.